# how to make the text align on all screen like this

Tags: flutter, dart, text, layout

the text work fine on one device but on other screens the text is messy so please help me to reduce scale of this container
i want to make it run on all screens like this image [image preview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnvPR.png) and the output on my screen is like this but on other screen is messy

```
 Container(
              width: 350,
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: GetJuz(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else {
                    var ayat = snapshot.data!;
                    var ayah = "";
                    for (var i = 12; i < 23; i++) {
                      ayah += ayat[i].codes!.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    }

                    return Container(
                      child: RichText(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        text: TextSpan(
                          children: [
                            for (var element in ayat) ...[
                              if (element.page == "5")
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: element.codes
                                      .toString()
                                      .replaceAll(" ", ""),
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () {
                                      print(element.text);
                                    },
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Schyler',
                                    fontSize:
                                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                            0.05,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ],
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of how you want the output to be? It will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
 fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05, // This will adjus the font size
```

I am not sure about this one, but you just try

Comment: still messy is there a way to keep the fontsize and reduce the scale of container

Comment: `return Transform.scale(
          scale: 0.8,
          child: Container(
            child: RichText(.` Transform.scale widget can be used to adjust the scale of the Container and its contents,[Transform Doc of flutter ](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.scale.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the text to be aligned equally from both ends. If that is the case, you can use this in RichText

```
 RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
      ......
)
```